# hasNext code in Java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble opening a file. The `hasNext` seems to crashing with the following error `java.lang.NullPointer`. This is my the code that's erring out (with `hasNext`).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Customers{
private Scanner opener;

    public void openFile() {
        try {
            opener = new Scanner (new File ("customer.txt"));
        } catch (Exception f) {
            System.out.println("Can not read file.");
        }
    }

    public void readFile() {
        while(opener.hasNext()) {
            String a = opener.next();
            String b = opener.next();
            String c = opener.next();

            System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", a, b, c);
        }
    }

    public void closeFile() {
        opener.close();
    }

}
```

and this is the other class:

```
public class fileTest {
public static void main (String args []) {
    Customers c = new Customers();
    c.openFile();
    c.readFile();
    c.closeFile();
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure your scanner is getting initialized? Look in your console for the output "Can not read file."

Comment: Maybe there is an exception in your openFile() method. Try to print the stacktrace. Because of the exception you variable opener wasn't able to initialized.

Comment: @Xelza can you show us the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: stacktrace? I did not made any :O

Comment: at the catch of your openFile() instead of using System.out.println("Can not read file.");, replace it with f.printStackTrace(); you can see the error log at your console.

Comment: these are the errors I am getting so far:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: customer.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
 at Customers.openFile(Customers.java:8)
 at fileTest.main(fileTest.java:5)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Customers.readFile(Customers.java:15)
 at fileTest.main(fileTest.java:6)

Comment: debug please. Its trivial, some input problems, either file path or name or extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but you *seem* to be saying that `opener.hasNext()` is throwing an NPE.

If so, that means that `opener` is `null`.  That in turn means that either you are not calling `openFile()` OR you are calling it but it is not working.  I suspect the latter, especially since the `main` method does call `openFile()`.

If the `openFile()` method fails to open the file (e.g. because it doesn't exist with the pathname as given), then a message is printed and `opener` remains `null`.  This is probably what is happening.

---

The `openFile()` method has a number of flaws:

1. it is catching `Exception` ... which could catch other exceptions than the one(s) you are expecting.
2. it is not logging the stacktrace or the actual exception message
3. it is *assuming* that the problem is due to not being able to open the file ... when it could possibly be something else (in general, if not in this particular case),
4. once it has printed the error message, it just continues *as if nothing bad had happened*.

The NPE problems are then a consequence of the `openFile()` flaws.

Note that if you print out the actual exception message, it should tell you why the application is unable to open the file.

**UPDATE**

The error message `customer.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)` is clearly telling you that it can't find the file.  The chances are that your application's current directory is not the directory that contains that file.  Since you used a relative pathname, you told it it look in the current directory.  The solution is to either use an absolute (full) pathname ... or make sure your application is launched with the right current directory.

---

Once you get past this problem, there is a problem in the way that you are reading the file.  The `readFile()` method is assuming that it is going to be able to read multiples of 3 tokens (strings) from the input.  If there is a problem with the file format, you are liable to get an (unchecked) exception.  You probably should catch this exception and produce a diagnostic ... rather than assuming that nothing bad can happen.

Comment: I have made changes to the exact location of the file, but still does not fix the problem. I placed the text file inside the project package in the first place, but still...

Comment: Are you using the **absolute** pathname for the file?  Starting from the root of the file system?  With the correct drive letter (on Windows)?

Comment: I actually solved my own problem , thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 4):

**opener might be null as there could be an exception in opening the file**

```
public void openFile() throws Exception{

            opener = new Scanner (new File ("customer.txt"));
    }
```

If there is any exception in opening the file, then just a message is printed and opener remains null which will lead to NPE in opener.hasNext()

You should not catch the exception instead throw the exception because if you are not able to open the file, then the code should fail and the other methods should not execute.

Comment: The point is, openFile() should fail fast in your case. If it doesnot fail here itself, then it will fail somewhere else which will lead to an error which is totally unrelated as you can see in this case as well. opener.next() leading to NPE in second call.

Answer (score 0):

First:Make sure your file actually exists in the disk, it is possible to create a `File` object even if the file does not exists.

Second:You are checkin for one element by doin `opener.hasNext()` and accessing next 3 elements!

When there is only one element in the list `opener.hasNext()` return `true` but you are accessing next 2 elements which are not present! hence the null pointer exception

Comment: but that shouldn't cause null pointer exception in `opener.hasNext()`

Answer (score 0):

your `opener` is not getting initialized that why the null pointer exception, make sure the file exists there and just try to give absolute path of the file

Comment: the files i did get here exist.

Comment: @Xelza - but they might not be in the application's current directory.

Comment: i made a package project named System, inside it are the classes and the text files.

Comment: did you try with absolute path just to try?

Answer (score 0):

Check few points here:

1. Is your program reading the file specified?If you are using eclipse,keep your file in src folder and give path as opener = new Scanner (new File ("src/customer.txt"));

2.The second problem with your code is you are only checking once for  while(opener.hasNext()) for next element and then reading three elements String a = opener.next();
            String b = opener.next();
            String c = opener.next(); .If there is no next element in your file you will get an exception ,check for each element before accessing it.

use this code instead:

public void readFile() {
        while(opener.hasNext()) {
            String a = opener.next();
            System.out.printf("%s\n", a);
        }
    }